# What propels the refrigerant in a refrigerator?

Tags: thermodynamics

A refrigerator works by moving cold refrigerant in the walls to absorb the heat. But what causes this refrigerant to move?

[image]

Comment: An electric refrigerator has a pump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The refrigerant is moved around the fridge by a pump called a *compressor*. This both compresses the coolant and pumps it.

There is a nice description of how compressors work [on this web site from a company that sells compressors](https://www.compressorsunlimited.com/blog/how-a-refrigeration-compressor-works).

Answer (score 4):

To add to John Rennie's answer:

This is correct for refrigerators that run on electricity. There is another popular class of refrigerators that run on natural gas or propane, using a cycle called *ammonia absorption* or (in the USA) the *servel cycle*.

In these refrigerators (commonly used in RV's, boats, and camping trailers, etc. in compact form) a small flame boils an ammonia/water mixture into mixed vapor, which rises up in a pipe from the flame heat exchanger and is then cleverly separated into separate streams of water vapor and ammonia vapor. Cooling fins carry away the heat in each, and then in the top of the refrigerator (where the ice cubes reside) these separate streams of cooled ammonia gas and water (condensed from the vapor) are piped in and mixed together again. The heat of solution is supplied by the contents of the refrigerator, which become chilled by the cold solution of ammonia in water. Ice cubes result. This mixture then flows back down to the bottom of the fridge through more pipes to where the flame is located, and the cycle repeats.

Servel refrigerators have no moving parts at all and are driven by heat from the flame, and thence by gravity, by which means the gases and fluids inside the pipes circulate continuously. They contain no mechanical pumps- the fluid movement (i.e., pump work) is all provided by density differences and gravity.

Servel fridges were once available in full-sized form factors which contained multi-gallon capacity kerosene tanks in their bottoms, which would maintain the little flame for weeks at a time.

Comment: you can still get them in Greece, they make them now with the possibility both of gas and electricity, for places with bad electricity supply, or even none. or even for economy, if the house is on gas for heating . https://www.citygas.gr/el/psigeia-igraerioi-cook-master

Comment: @SolomonSlow, will edit. -NN

Comment: Also see the [Einstein-Szilárd 
refrigerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_refrigerator), an absorption fridge with 3 working fluids that operates at constant pressure, with no moving parts, apart from the movement of the fluids, of course. ;)